# Nodejs logger that enforces certain meta

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, logging, lambda

Looking for a logging solution for aws lambda where I can enforce developers to provide certain fields to the logger. For example, I like developers to attach service_name and correlation id to each log, no matter what is being logged or log level. Motivation behind this is to be able to track all logs related to a certain correlation id among all cloudwatch logs generated by multiple lambdas. Thank you!